# How do I prevent wood from warping?

Tags: wood, wooden-furniture

I have an electricity inspection box inside the house.  What I'd like to do is build a small wooden cabinet to enclose it (it is flush to the wall).  I've measured up and bought five pieces of wood:

#### . 2 x 45mm x 15mm x 700mm

#### . 2 x 45mm x 15mm x 800mm

#### . 1 x 15mm x 700mm x 800mm

My intention is to surround it with the thin pieces and use the fifth piece as a door.  However, the thin piece have already started to warp (I've had the wood for around a month).  Is there any way to prevent this, or does anyone have any tips for doing a similar thing?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I do have a couple questions =) 1) Is the location subject to temperature, humidity, or moisture fluctuations? 2) What type of wood are you using?

Comment: 3) What's the purpose of the enclosure? To hide the inspection box? To be on the safe side, I'd double-check with your regional fire codes as there may be safety considerations involved here.

Comment: @Mike - 1. The area is subject the temperature fluctuations, as it's very close to a radiator. 2. Pine. 3. Yes - that is the purpose, and thanks, I will check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pine that thin is going to warp; if you're going to paint it, I'd use MDF. If you want a natural wood look, a plywood with a finish-grade top layer would be much more stable.

Answer (score 2):

Other than using another, more stable, material like plywood; you could try screwing each board to a cleat, which is a piece of wood attached with screws across the inside face of the board. With material that thin, maybe you could make a frame using thicker stock and screw each panel to a frame. When you finish it, try to apply the same finish to all the surfaces so the moisture gets in and out evenly. Also, when you put the box together try to arrange it so that all the sides have the grain going in the same direction.

http://www.finewoodworking.com/media/TabletopsFlat.pdf